# Single query to retrieve multiple values from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

Expenses table

```
1/1/2016  exp1  2000
13/1/2016 exp11 2500
1/2/2016  exp2  1500
1/3/2016  exp3  1000
10/3/2016 exp1  2000
```

Income table

```
1/1/2016  income1 2500
1/2/2016  income2 3500
1/3/2016  income3 1500
10/3/2016 income3 1000
1/4/2016  income4 5000
```

From single query what I need is group by month, this is what I need

```
Expenses Incomes Month
4500     2500    Jan
1500     3500    Feb
3000     2500    Mar
0        5000    April
```

I need the above query to show the data in Google graph

Comment: Explain what is the relationship.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Please add the complete table structure and the expected table/row you're looking for. Also include the code you have tried so far. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details on how to ask a good question.

Comment: After you figure out how to write the query, putting it in a google graph is a completely different task. You will need to try code, then ask a new detailed question if it doesn't work (with a sample of what you have tried).

Answer (score 0):

Terrible data structure and format, but not impossible:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(exp.Expenses,0) Expenses, 
    IFNULL(inc.Incomes,0) Incomes, 
    inc.`monthname` `Month`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(i.amount) Incomes,
            MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(i.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')) `monthname`,
            MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(i.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')) `month`
        FROM
            incomes i
        GROUP BY
            MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(i.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')),
            MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(i.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y'))
    ) inc

LEFT JOIN

    (
    SELECT
        SUM(e.amount) Expenses,
        MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(e.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')) `monthname`,
        MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(e.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')) `month`
    FROM
        expenses e
    GROUP BY
        MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(e.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')),
        MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(e.`date`, '%d/%m/%Y'))
    ) exp
ON exp.`month` = inc.`month`

ORDER BY
    inc.`month`
```

Output of this simplicity:

```
+----------+---------+----------+
| Expenses | Incomes | Month    |
+----------+---------+----------+
| 4500     | 2500    | January  |
| 1500     | 3500    | February |
| 3000     | 2500    | March    |
| 0        | 5000    | April    |
+----------+---------+----------+
4 rows in set
```

Anyway better thing seriously how to improve and normalize your data.

Comment: Can you please let me know what's wrong in my table structure. I just created two tables. 1 for expenses and 1 for incomes. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I give the number of the month rather than text. I'll leave it to you to convert it to text (using a CASE expression, for example) if you wish:

```
SELECT
    sum(expense) AS total_expense, sum(income) AS total_income, trans_month
FROM (
    SELECT
        month(trans_date) AS trans_month,
        0 AS income,
        sum(amount) AS expense
    FROM expense
    GROUP BY month(trans_date)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        month(trans_date) AS trans_month,
        sum(amount) AS income,
        0 AS expense
    FROM income
    GROUP BY month(trans_date)
) AS a
GROUP BY trans_month;
```